# GridView SelectedIndexChanging event, find text in TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have grid and it's selectIndexchanging event.

my aspx code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvClients" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"
               BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None"
    OnRowEditing="gvClients_RowEditing"  Font-Size="Medium" 
    onrowcancelingedit="gvClients_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowdeleting="gvClients_RowDeleting" onrowupdating="gvClients_RowUpdating" 
    onselectedindexchanging="gvClients_SelectedIndexChanging">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/Cancel.png"
            UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" EditImageUrl="~/images/Edit.png" ItemStyle-Width="25px"
            UpdateText="Update" CancelText="Cancel" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" ButtonType="Image"
            ItemStyle-Width="25px" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgSelect" CommandName="Select" AlternateText="Select"
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/allowed.png" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ClientId" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ClientId")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtClientClientId" Text='<%#Eval("ClientId") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ClientName" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ClientName")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtClientClientName" Text='<%#Eval("ClientName") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Active")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtClientActive" Text='<%#Eval("Active") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Size="Smaller" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
</asp:GridView>
```

now, my `SelectedIndexChanging` code:

```
protected void gvClients_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvClients.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    txtClientNumber.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
}
```

issue is, text coming null . there is data but instead of value it's coming null....also same code is working on another page. so, kindly let me know. what wrong i did?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `TemplateFields` instead of `BoundFields` the `Cell.Text` is always empty. You either have to

- use a control in the `TemplateField` and use `row.FindControl(id)` to find it(what i recommend)
- or you have to cast the first control to [`DataBoundLiteralControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databoundliteralcontrol.aspx) which is a little bit strange since you cannot see that control. It is automatically added to the cell's control collection.

  ```
  GridViewRow row = gvClients.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
  txtClientNumber.Text = ((ITextControl)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
  ```

Comment: thx for your suggestion...actually as per your answer result come like: "\r\n                                                                  Atomic Park.com'\r\n                                                                " ....but i used Trim funciton...and result come like i want.Thanks again